# Display countries in alphabetical order?

Tags: java

I have a list to display countries in alphabetical order in the drop down.

But I want India and USA to be displayed first and rest in alphabetical order.
How can I do it?

Comment: with an extra sort order column....

Comment: One way would be to just sort the list, then remove India and USA from the list and finally add them at indexes 0 and 1 of the very same list. Not a JSF problem, just basic Java. JSF is merely the presenter here, not the sorter.

Comment: What drop down? GUI? HTML from your webapp?

Answer (score 3):

Put those two in a different list and remaining countries in a different list then add those two lists using use `addAll()`

Comment: I tried to write a Comparable based solution, but maybe later :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this,

```
 void sortCountries(List<String> countriesToSort){
   countriesToSort.remove("India");
   countriesToSort.remove("Usa");

   Collections.sort(countriesToSort, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

   countriesToSort.add(0, "India");
   countriesToSort.add(0, "Usa");
 }
```